# how to get contacts added or edited date in address book using iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, addressbook

How to get contacts added and edited dates in iPhone sdk. Give me example code it will help full for me.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: "Give me example code it will help full for me". That is not how this site works. First off, I do not believe that there is any way to do this. Second, what have you attempted so far, where have you looked, etc. Third, this is not just a place where you ask people to just "give you code." People don't have to help you, and they (we) will not just give you answers if it appears you have put little effort in so far.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get the created and modified dates of contacts.  You need to read the documentation for [ABPerson](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007210-CH991-SW3), as well as the [Address Book Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html).

When you have a ABRecordRef, you can pull its modified and created dates by using

```
CFTypeRef ABRecordCopyValue (
   ABRecordRef record,
   ABPropertyID property
);
```

The ABPropertyID constants are listed in documentation for ABPerson.

```
const ABPropertyID kABPersonCreationDateProperty;
const ABPropertyID kABPersonModificationDateProperty
```